# Rendering .Rmd file on Google drive to update webpage

Tags: r, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, r-markdown

Disclaimer: I am not a website developer, but I know R fairly well. So please excuse my lack of knowledge about website development if you find the question below trivial.

I have a webpage that I am generating with an RMarkdown script. The excel file is subject to frequent changes. Currently, I manually regenerate the html page using the code and upload it on the server (using Bitvise SSH client).

I had the following in mind to automate this process:

The excel is on a google drive so I can create a `.bat` file to run the code at fixed time points to generate html. Since the webpage will be created in the google drive, the web address of the page can be directly a google drive link for the html file.

As the rendering is happening locally, the process depends entirely on the PC which runs the batch file. I just saw that there are ways to execute R scripts in google sheets using app scripts. So I was wondering is it also possible to write a code (where? app script?) on Google which renders the html from `.Rmd` code in fixed time intervals and updates the html?

(I want to do this all free of cost)

Comment: If the html is already created, you can render it using `HtmlService`. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and search for more details.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Since the webpage will be created in the google drive, the web address of the page can be directly a google drive link for the html file.

Google Drive provides several "links" for each file stored on it; however, don't assume that these links could open an HTML as if a web server hosted them. Google Drive used to have a feature that made this possible, but it was removed several years ago.

From the question

> I just saw that there are ways to execute R scripts in google sheets using app scripts.

I'm sorry, I haven't seen this.

From the question

> So I was wondering is it also possible to write a code (where? app script?) on Google which renders the html from .Rmd code in fixed time intervals and updates the html?

Google Apps Script could get the content of a file stored in Google Drive. It hasn't built-in support for parse HTML, for this, you will need to write some code or use a library like Cheerio.